# CR/LF issue for file copied from Mac

Tags: c, file

I have written a simple application which will read the file line by line  and display it. For the file copied from Linux or Windows machines using FTP, it is working fine. But for files copied from Mac OS X, the first character of the line is not showing when I print the line.

How to handle the file copied from Mac OS X also?

Example file:

```
Hello world 1
Hello world 2
```

Display after read line by line:

```
ello world 1
ello world 2
```

Code:

```c
/*****Function to add the NULL termination at end of line*********/ 

my_func(char *str, int len)
{
    if(len)
    {
        if(str[len-1] != '\r') 
        {
            str[len] = '\0';
        }
        else
        {
            str[len-1] = '\0'
        }
    }
    else
    {
        str[len]='\0';
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the sample file in a hex editor?

Comment: The file copied from OS X will be equivalent to the file copied from Linux unless you go to extraordinary lengths to write the file in some other way (or unless you mean Mac OS 9 or earlier — but those machines should be dead by now; it's been about 15 years since Mac OS 9 was last released).  You need to look hard at the actual bytes in the line.  For example, `for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) printf(" %.2X", (unsigned char)str[i]); putchar('\n');` in the function would show you the bytes printed in hex.  You'd be looking for `0A` and `0D` (`\n` and `\r`) mainly, and perhaps `08` (`\b`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you want to look for line feed `\n` *and* carriage return `\r`.  Depending on the system, you can get either one of these, or both together.  So you may want to adjust your function somewhat.

If `len` contains the length of a single line in the buffer, and you just want to trim off trailing newline character(s), you could simply do something like this:

```
while( len > 0 && (str[len-1] == '\n' || str[len-1] == '\r') ) --len;
str[len] = '\0';
```